# How to make a web service url work on a remote machine?

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I have developed a REST based web service that works perfectly on my machine. The URL is

```
http://localhost:8080/MyRESTProject/resources/welcome/
```

Obviously, the URL would work only on my machine. What I want is the URL to work on any remote machine. Also, I want the service to run constantly. Is this possible even after I terminate the web service process?

**PS**: I am using eclipse dynamic web project to build this web service and the OS is windows 7.

Comment: This is very broad. it's also impossible to answer without much more information: what operating system and development environment are you using here?

Comment: I am using eclipse and windows..

Comment: instead of localhost if you put your private IP address, then your web service will be available to devices in your private network. If you want it to be publicly available you have to configure your router accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web service will be available as long as it is being hosted. A web server receives HTTP requests and replies with HTTP responses. How can you expect your web service to continue working if you terminate the server process?

As for your web service being accessible from outside, you will need to know the public IP address of your network. You can search "What is my public IP" on Google search to get your answer.

But you are not done yet, you will need to configure your router/firewall  to open up a port on your router and map it to port 8080 on your host.

Comment: thanx for the first part of the answer....for the second part would the url look something like this   http://ip_address:8080/MyRESTProject/resources/welcome/  after configuring the firewall

Comment: it could, if you map port 8080 on your router to port 8080 on your computer. otherwise it will be public_ip_address:portNum/....

Comment: if the port number isn't specified in the url (with modifications as you said), then will it work?

Comment: no it will not, because if you do not supply a port number, the browser (or client of any kind) will try to guess the port number based on the protocol. for example for HTTP it will try to use port 80 by default. I would not recommend you use port 80 for your custom web applications.